# Splicing/Removing selected array elements removes the other elements after the selected element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am making an offline application of a music website using JS and I am handling song queues using arrays. I added song blocks with skip buttons so users can choose which song to skip without spamming another skip button that only allows them to skip the first song of the queue. The problem is, splicing the array with the index of the selected song the users wanted to skip removes the rest of the songs after it.

Example array: `["songA","songB","songC","songD","songE"]`

If the user choose to skip songC, the song queue will become `["songA","songB"]` and the songC to songE will be removed, but in reality the expected outcome should be `["songA","songB","songD","songE"]`.

I have no idea what is wrong with the code and I have searched similar topics regarding this problem but still no results. I am still new to JS and my code's a bit rough but I'm pretty sure that's not the cause of the issue.

JS:

```
//function of skip buttons on song blocks
songPlaylist.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() { 
    iconList = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteIcon");
    iconList.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function() {  
            var nameOfSong = this.parentNode.childNodes[0].dataset.name;
            var indexByName = songQueue.indexOf(nameOfSong);
            var selectedBlock = this.parentNode;              

            if (songQueue.length == 1) {
                songQueue.shift();
                songPlaylist.removeChild(songPlaylist.firstChild);
                var emptyMsgSpan = document.createElement("div");
                emptyMsgSpan.className += "emptyMsgSpan";
                var emptyMsg = document.createTextNode("Playlist is empty! How 'bout adding some music?");
                emptyMsgSpan.appendChild(emptyMsg);
                document.getElementById("playlistContainer").appendChild(emptyMsgSpan);        
                setTimeout(function() {
                    audioPlayer.src = "";
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                songQueue.splice(indexByName,1); // <---  press first block output delete everything
                                                //        press any block after first deletes everything beneath it
                songPlaylist.removeChild(selectedBlock);    
                for (var blockIndex = indexByName; blockIndex <= songQueue.length; blockIndex++) {
                    document.getElementById("playlistContainer").children[blockIndex].childNodes[1].dataset.index -= 1;
                }
            };
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bai+Jamjuree" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jost&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<div>Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/roundicons" title="Roundicons">Roundicons</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a></div>--> 
<title>Mue - Custom Playlist</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg">
        <div class="titleBar">
            <button style="background: none; border: none; cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.reload(); return false;">
               <span>MUE</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="songNameDisplay">
            <span id="nowPlaying"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="trackContainer">
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="audioTrack">
                <div class="trackBtn"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="skipBtn">
                <div class="triangle1"></div>
                <div class="triangle2"></div>
                <div class="rect"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="fileBtn" class="fileBtn"><span>Upload</span></button>
    </div>
    <audio id="audioPlayer" controls autoplay></audio>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <div id="playlistContainer"></div>
</body>   
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
    const bg = document.getElementById("bg");

    window.addEventListener('scroll' , function() {
        let offset= window.pageYOffset;
        bg.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * 0.5 + "px";
    });
    </script>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `songQueue.splice(indexByName,1);` will definitely **only** remove the one entry at index `indexByName`. Please reduce the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Side note re `songPlaylist.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted"` - DOM mutation events were deprecated ***years*** ago. Use [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead if you can't avoid needing to listen for DOM mutation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for pointing out that DOM mutation events were deprecated. That made me review my code again and find more answers on the web. All I had to do was just apply a simple concept of event delegation in my code and it works fine now. Still don't know why it deletes everything and not just 1 entry though. Thanks again.